# How to make editable rows efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've a query, im using js to make a table tds editable. Im able to do this with individual methods on edit button .

I want to know what will be more efficient way to code this so that each edit onclick make that particular row only and in future if I increase table rows , it should be able to do it.

Right now im assigning id to the tr and targeting its row items , which is working but seems to be inefficient.

something like

```
var toBeEdited = document.getElementById('first-tr').getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (let i = 0; i < toBeEdited.length; i++) {
    toBeEdited[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
  }
```

Here's the reference code for example

`https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/jyx2k7cv/3/`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no need to make it individually as you have it now and call explicit methods on each button. You can select all your buttons with the querySelectorAll() method, then check it's parent TR and iterate over all it's td children and make them editable. That way you have it dynamic and crisp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the below snippet, we can edit the `td` on clicking `edit` and edit feature will be disabled on focus out of the content editable item

```js
makeEditable = function(){
var el = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
Object.keys(el.children).forEach(function(i){
  el.children[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  el.children[i].setAttribute('onblur', 'disableEdit()');
});
}
disableEdit = function(){
var el = event.target.parentElement;
Object.keys(el.children).forEach(function(i){
  el.children[i].removeAttribute('contenteditable', true);
});
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Header 1</th>
                      <th>Header 2</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr id="first-tr">
                      <td>Name</td>
                      <td>Location 1</td>
                      <td class="text-nowrap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-first-tr" onclick="makeEditable()">
                          Edit
                        </button>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="second-tr">
                      <td>Name 2</td>
                      <td>Location 1</td>
                      <td class="text-nowrap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-second-tr" onclick="makeEditable()">
                          Edit
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="third-tr">
                      <td>Name 3</td>
                      <td>Location 3</td>
                      <td class="text-nowrap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-third-tr" onclick="makeEditable()">
                           Edit
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Hi @Akhil , thanks for this, this seems to be a correct solution to my problem :)

Comment: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Comment: @Oen44, change 'onclick="makeEditable()"' to 'onclick="makeEditable(event)"'

Comment: @AkhilAravind This is not for me to change, you should do that. Provide working answer.

Comment: @Oen44, it depends on the browser and the one who codes, I provided an answer for chrome which is widely used. The one who knows every browser can kick this issue without scratching head.

Answer (score 1):

Update `onclick="makeEditable(this)"` on element. Here `this` will be the current `td` element object.

Use one parameter with function as `makeEditable = (td) => {...`

And use `var toBeEdited = td.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('td');` for fetching respective `tr` childs.

```js
makeEditable = (td) => {
  var toBeEdited = td.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (let i = 0; i < toBeEdited.length; i++) {
    if (toBeEdited[i].getElementsByTagName('button').length == 0) {
      toBeEdited[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="first-tr">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-first-tr" onclick="makeEditable(this)">
                          Edit
                        </button>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="second-tr">
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-second-tr" onclick="makeEditable(this)">
                          Edit
                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="third-tr">
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Location 3</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Edit" id="edit-third-tr" onclick="makeEditable(this)">
                           Edit
                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Karan , thanks for this but yea the button text itself becomes editable here

Comment: Updated code. Added condition `if (toBeEdited[i].getElementsByTagName('button').length == 0)`